# How Can I create an authenticated user from ldap

Tags: symfony, ldap

I have a login page on my symfony2 application.
That only users in an remote active directory can connect.
And I would like to create a user on my oracle database for every new user who connect on my app.

How can I handle that ?

Im using [FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) and the [LDAP Component](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-ldap-component)

I can't find a way to hook the login success to implement an user creation or orverride the symfony ldap core component.

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Since the LDAP Component is a user provider you can create a Listener on the [symfony authentication events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events)

Comment: Thanks for your help. And It is posible to replace the session user by the new I created on the event handler ?

Comment: Ok, it seems I misunderstood your question. FOSUserBundle and LDAP Component are actually both user providers. What you need is  a [custom authentication provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html), so when someone try to authenticate but is unknow by your database, you call your ldap to create a new account from it

Comment: I dont want to create the user to the ldap. The ldap is on read only. I would like to create on my app database every user logged using the ldap that have never logged in before. And finaly use the new created user as the current session user logged in.

Comment: Yeah, what i meant is : if db does not know a user, you call the ldap. If ldap know it then you can safely create a user into db and authenticate this new user otherwise you return 401

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what Im looking for. Thanks a lot!